# Request timeout while uploading file in cloudinary using nodejs, multer

Tags: node.js, request, timeout, multer, cloudinary

```
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
const getDataUri = (file) => {
  const parser = new DataUriParser();
  const extName = path.extname(file.originalname).toString();
  return parser.format(extName, file.buffer);
};

export const createCourse = catchAsyncError(async (req, res, next) => {
  const { title, description, category, createdBy } = req.body;

  if (!title || !description || !category || !createdBy)
    return next(new ErrorHandler("Please add all fields", 400));

  const file = req.file;
  const fileUri = getDataUri(file);

  const mycloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(fileUri.content, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  });

  await Course.create({
    title,
    description,
    category,
    createdBy,
    poster: {
      public_id: mycloud.public_id,
      url: mycloud.secure_url,
    },
  })

  res.status(201).json({
    success: true,
    message: "Course Created Successfully. You can add lectures now",
  })
});
```

When I am directly putting an image URL in place of `fileUri.content` then it is getting uploaded, otherwise it is showing request timeout even for 2kb file.

When we `console.log(fileUri.content)` we get:

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Comment: It seems like your code is incomplete, and it gets cut off at the end. Could you provide the remaining part of your code or specify the particular issue or question you're facing?

You can try increasing the server timeout, checking file size, verifying Cloudinary and Multer configurations, considering chunked file uploads for large files, updating packages and more...

Comment: I have tried every possible solution like i am uploading 6kb size image only then also it is giving request timeout, increases the timeout time, updated the packages, and also cloudinary and multer are working fine i have checked  them but it is not able to upload the uri i don't know why. I have tried to upload an url directly then it worked but not with this URI.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is just use another wifi network.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).